# Filter subscription confirmation includes $BaseWebsiteAddress in the text/plain part

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

I just subscribed to a tag on scifi.se and the text/plain part of the mail reads like the following:

> #### [Confirm Subscription]($BaseWebsiteAddress/filters/email-confirm/xxxxx)

which doesn't seem right.

Comment: They even compose emails in Markdown... impressive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oops, after a bit of refactoring, I accidentally removed the logic that replaces `$BaseWebsiteAddress` with `http://stackexchange.com` in the plain-text emails.

This is fixed now, thanks.